# htaccess: Remove trailing slash from URL ending with .xml/ only

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, genesis-theme-framework, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I need to remove trailing slash from URLs ending with `.xml/` only .. For this purpose I've created a Rewrite Condition and Rule which is working perfectly fine for the test link http://website.com/test.xml/

Test Link: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=6fe08232-438a-53fa-8f1a-1f7f69b77b6f

The problem is when I place the rule in WordPress `.htaccess` file, it doesn't work at all! Seems like WordPress or YOAST Permalink structure is overriding the rule .. please help!

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*).xml/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1.xml [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Note:

Please note that this is not a physical file .. using rewrite rules to generate sitemap on the run! This is a wordpress page in fact!

`add_rewrite_rule('([^/]*)-placeholder.xml','index.php?page_id=123&custom‌​-slug=$matches[1]','‌​top');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly worked out for me ..

The issue was due to WordPress canonical redirects .. The use of `/%postname%/` in permalink structure was redirecting the custom template to the trailing slash URL.

I simply removed the `template_redirect` filter for canonical redirects .. and now the link works in both cases i.e. with or without trailing slash.

Here is my code for reference.. 1234 is the example page id for the template used to generate dynamic sitemap.

`//Disabling canonical redirects for sitemap
function disable_sitemap_redirect() {
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
    $current_url = $current_url . $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
    $id = url_to_postid($current_url);
    if($id == 1234) : remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical'); endif;
}
add_action('init', 'disable_sitemap_redirect', 10, 0);`

Answer (score 2):

If you're outputting a sitemap, there's no reason to wait for the query for your page- which is what is producing the redirect.

Hook an earlier action and you won't need anything to counter the trailing slash, because it won't happen-

**EDIT**

Here's a complete version with registering query vars, rules, and `parse_request` action:

```
// add the custom query vars
// WordPress will not parse query vars in rules
// if they are not added to the list of valid query vars
function wpd_sitemap_query_var( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'svc-slug';
    $vars[] = 'svc-offset';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_sitemap_query_var' );

// add the rules
function wpd_sitemap_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '([^/]*)-svc-([0-9]+).xml',
        'index.php?page_id='.get_field('dynamic_sitemap','option').'&svc-slug=$matches[1]&svc-offset=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '([^/]*)-svc.xml',
        'index.php?page_id='.get_field('dynamic_sitemap','option').'&svc-slug=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'wpd_sitemap_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);

// intercept the query and test if our query var is set
// this means one of our rules matched and we should show the sitemap
function wpd_sitemap_parse_request( $query ){
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['svc-slug'] ) ){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $query->query_vars );
        echo '</pre>';

        // halt further execution after sitemap is output
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_sitemap_parse_request' );
```

Comment: The sitemap being generated is for dynamic pages which don't exist at all!

I need to override WordPress's permalink settings from `/%postname%/` to `/%postname%` ..

Comment: I understand what your problem is and this solves it, have you tested it? This works in conjunction with your rule, to intercept and display your site maps without the trailing slash redirect. You must also be sure to register `custom-slug` query var with [the query vars filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars).

Comment: Tried it .. it didn't work!

Comment: Tried what? Did you remove the code from .htaccess? This does not use htaccess. Did you add the `custom-slug` query var with the `query_vars` filter? If you simply look at the contents of `$query` within the `parse_request` filter, you will see your query var appear whenever your rule is matched, does this not occur? Again- I do this quite regularly for exactly this, it is tested and working with current WP version.

Comment: Yes, I removed the code from `.htaccess` and also used the custom slug for the selected page template .. it didn't work out for me!

`function my_site_map( $query ){
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['svc-sitemap'] ) ){
        echo 'output headers and sitemap here';
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'my_site_map' );`

Comment: Where did you put this code, and how do you register the `svc-sitemap` query var? You are clearly missing something. It isn’t a page template slug, it’s a query var.

Comment: here are the rules .. first one for paginated sitemap .. and the second one for parent sitemap ..

`//Sitemap Rules
    add_rewrite_rule('([^/]*)-svc-([0-9]+).xml','index.php?page_id='.get_field('dynamic_sitemap','option').'&svc-slug=$matches[1]&offset=$matches[2]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('([^/]*)-svc.xml','index.php?page_id='.get_field('dynamic_sitemap','option').'&svc-slug=$matches[1]','top');`

Comment: see edit above.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ /%1.xml [L]
> ```

This should be an *external redirect*, not an *internal rewrite*. (Otherwise it won't look like it's doing anything, as the visible URL won't change.) So, you need the `R` (`redirect`) flag. For example:

```
 RewriteRule ^ /%1.xml [R,L]
```

This is a temporary (302) redirect. Change `R` to `R=301` to make it a permanent (301) redirect - but only when you are sure it's working OK. (Since 301s are cached hard by the browser and can make testing problematic.)

However, you don't need the `RewriteCond` directive. This can be done in a single `RewriteRule` (it will also be more efficient to do so). This should also go *before* your existing *internal rewrites* and ideally *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` block, as otherwise your customisation could be overridden in future updates.

So, all you need is (at the top of your file):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.xml/$ /$1.xml [R,L]
```

Remember to escape literal dots in your regex.

**UPDATE:** And yes, that should be `$1` (as a backreference to the `RewriteRule` *pattern*) as opposed to `%1` (a backreference to the last matched *CondPattern*).

Comment: Is it `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.xml/$ /$1.xml [R,L]` .. $1.xml instead of %1.xml?

Comment: It's giving an error ... `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` When I use custom Permalink Structure `/%postname%` it works fine.. but `/%postname%/` is required .. so I guess WordPress permalink structure is overriding the rule somehow!

Comment: Sorry, yes - `$1` instead of `%1` in the updated rule. I've fixed that in my answer.

Comment: Please help out over redirect issue .. this was there before as well!

Comment: Does this `.xml` URL not map to a physical file? It is generated by WordPress? What "redirects" do you see in the network traffic?

Comment: This is not a physical file .. using rewrite rules to generate sitemap on the run! This is a wordpress page in fact!
`add_rewrite_rule('([^/]*).xml','index.php?page_id=123&custom-slug=$matches[1]','top');`

Comment: This `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.xml/$ /$1.xml [R,L]` gives an error "Too many redirects!"

Comment: @HassanAlvi By itself, that wouldn't result in a redirect loop (ie. "Too many redirects" error). However, there would seem to be a conflict with your permalink structure, since this would add the trailing slash back again (via another redirect), which could then result in a redirect loop. Since this is a page within WordPress itself and WP is generating the URLs - I would think this needs to be resolved within WP itself, not `.htaccess`. You would seem to need a custom permalink for a specific URL(s) and another for the rest? Sorry, I'm unable to help further with that.